# Seemingly simple differential equation, $y'=(4x+y)/(x+4y)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

My friend has asked me for help solving the following differential equation (of which the explicit solutions are supposedly derivable):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4x+y}{x+4y}\tag{1}$$

I have tried hitting it with every technique I know, but none of my efforts have proved fruitful. Could you help me out? All I can end up with is a complicated implicit solution. I will now outline every approach I have taken. (Note: I have tagged every equation for referencing convenience).

**[Homogeneous Substitution]**

This equation is manifestly homogeneous when put in the following form:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4+\frac{y}{x}}{1+4\frac{y}{x}}\tag{2}$$

So let's try the substitution $u=y/x$. We can work out that $y'=xu'+u$, so plugging everything in gives us:

$$xu'+u=\frac{4+u}{1+4u}\tag{3}$$

$$\implies \frac{u'}{\frac{4+u}{1+4u}-u}=\frac{1}{x}\tag{4}$$

I can solve this by integrating both sides with respect to $x$ (left side requires heavy algebraic massaging):

$$\ln \left|(1-u)^{-5/8}(1+u)^{-3/8}\right|=\ln |x| +C\tag{5}$$

After re-substituting $u=y/x$, this then simplifies down to

$$(x-y)^5(x+y)^3=C\tag{6}$$

So the solution seems to be the solution to a eight-order polynomial, which I'm not sure can be solved for explicitly (well, it **should be** because why else would it show up on an entry-level DFQ homework assignment?). On top of that, a few of my previous steps have implicitly imposed domain restraints on my solution (e.g. every step where I divide by a quantity that could be zero). I've plotted the solution below, where I have taken note of the homogeneity of the original equation (the case where $C=0$ is special though - then the solutions are just $y=\pm x$).

[image]

**[Integrating Factor - Exact Equation]**

Ok, maybe the exact form of the solution is buried in that polynomial. Let's see if this can be made exact. Putting it in the standard form gives us:

$$f(x,y)dx+g(x,y)dy=0,$$

$$~~\textrm{where}~ f(x,y)=(4x+y)~~\textrm{and}~~ g(x,y)=-(x+4y)\tag{7}$$

This isn't an exact equation by itself ($f_y\neq g_x$). Moreover, no integrating factor of one variable (either $x$ or $y$) will work because calculating the integrating factor involves calculating an integral like:

$$\int \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}{g(x,y)}dx\tag{8}$$

and we can't do that integral explicitly because the numerator is a constant for the specific $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ in this problem, while the denominator is a full function of $x$ and $y$. So this seems to be a no go.

**[Laplace/D'Alembert Equation Form]**

A [Laplace or d'Alembert equation][2] (no, not *the* Laplace's equation or d'Alembert's solution/formula) is first-order ordinary differential equation of the type

$$y=xf(y')+g(y')\tag{9}$$

which can be morphed into the simpler linear equation:

$$\frac{dx}{d(y')}=\left(\frac{f'(y')}{y'-f(y')}\right)x+\frac{g'(y')}{y'-f(y')}\tag{10}$$

I have found that I can manipulate the original differential equation into the desired form:

$$y=\left(\frac{y'-4}{1-4y'}\right)x\tag{11}$$

from which we can read off (well, calculate really) the corresponding differential equation for $x(y')$:

$$\frac{dx}{d(y')}=-\frac{15x}{4(1-y'^2)(1-4y')}\tag{12}$$

This is separable. Solving this gives me:

$$\ln \left|\frac{(1-y')^{5/8}(1+y')^{3/8}}{4y'-1}\right|=\ln |x| +C\tag{13}$$

this seems to be the most highly nonlinear and implicit first-order differential equation that I have ever seen. I don't know what I could realistically do from here.

---

**~~ADDENDUM~~**

These are the exact instructions from the assignment

> $$\textrm{1. Find all solutions:}~~~~\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4x+y}{x+4y} $$

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/d%27Alembert

Comment: @Moo (1) No I don't see the sign error. The $1/x$ term on the right-side of Eq. (4) should be positive. (2) Your comment wasn't correctly typeset. [EDIT: Now you've corrected it]

Comment: Why do you think you can solve for $y$?  I don't see anything in the instructions that requires this.

Comment: @Paul I think it's clear why a student taking a standard first course in differential equations would think they should/could solve for $y$ here, since usually whenever only an implicit solution is possible it is stated explicitly (hehe, words). I don't really **know**, but it just seems odd that no mention of the complexity of this was made (which leads me to believe I'm messing something up).

Comment: Find all solutions doesn't mean *find an explicit form* for all solutions.

Comment: @Bye_World Well with the instructions provided, how does one know when to stop? One could say my implicit solution is "enough", but then couldn't one then just say "the solutions are all differentiable functions which satisfy the stated differential equation"?

Comment: Yes.  But there's an implicit assumption that one's characterisation of the solution set shouldn't involve any derivatives.  I agree though that if the solution is indeed supposed to be written in implicit form, then the statement of the exercise should have specified that.

Comment: I think the instruction wanted to say, find all solutions over $\Bbb R$, and then $y=\pm x$ will be enough....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you note, the equation is homogeneous. The form of the coefficient matrix[*] naturally suggests introducing new variables $u$ and $v$ by
$$
\begin{aligned}
  x &= u + v, \\
  y &= u - v;
\end{aligned}\qquad
\begin{aligned}
  dx &= du + dv, \\
  dy &= du - dv.
\end{aligned}
$$
The ODE becomes
$$
\frac{du - dv}{du + dv}
  = \frac{dy}{dx}
  = \frac{4x + y}{x + 4y}
  = \frac{5u + 3v}{5u - 3v},
\tag{1}
$$
or after rearrangement,
$$
\frac{dv}{du} = -\frac{3v}{5u}.
$$
Integrating gets you quickly to $v^5u^3 = C$, the solution you found, though possibly with less effort than getting from (4) to (5) in the original post.

A level curve $f(x, y) = C$ of a smooth function satisfying an ODE is generally considered a "solution".

---

[*] For what it's worth, this ODE can be expressed as the *linear* planar system
$$
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    dx \\
    dy \\
  \end{array}\right]
  = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    1 & 4 \\
    4 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x \\
    y \\
  \end{array}\right].
$$
The eigenvalues of the coefficient matrix are $1 \pm 4$, or $5$ and $-3$, and the vectors $(1, \pm1)$ are an eigenbasis (whose associated Cartesian coordinates are $u$ and $v$). It follows by (easy) linear algebra that parametric solutions are
\begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    x(t) \\
    y(t) \\
  \end{array}\right]
  &= \frac{1}{2}\left[\begin{array}{@{}cr@{}}
    1 &  1 \\
    1 & -1 \\
  \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
      e^{5t} &  0 \\
      0 & e^{-3t} \\
  \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}cr@{}}
      1 &  1 \\
      1 & -1 \\
    \end{array}\right]
  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      x(0) \\
      y(0) \\
    \end{array}\right] \\
  &= \frac{1}{2} \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
      e^{5t} + e^{-3t} & e^{5t} - e^{-3t} \\
      e^{5t} - e^{-3t} & e^{5t} + e^{-3t} \\
  \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      x(0) \\
      y(0) \\
    \end{array}\right] \\
  &= e^{t} \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
      \cosh(4t) & \sinh(4t) \\
      \sinh(4t) & \cosh(4t) \\
  \end{array}\right]  \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      x(0) \\
      y(0) \\
    \end{array}\right].
\end{align*}